# Photos automaticaly get deleted in lumia 800

Tags: 7.5, photos, nokia-lumia-800

I have a `Nokia Lumia 800` . Yesterday i found a problem that the photos taken on yesterday get deleted automatically. I am surprised that it have a free space of `6GB` . But i `lost all photos taken yesterday`.

If any body knows about this problem please help me.

Also let me know about the recovery tools for recovering those deleted photos

Comment: As far as I know there is an option in Zune where you can sync your photos and after that those photos are deleted from your phone. Is this the case?

Comment: nope.. Its automatically deleted after am taking so many photos

Comment: and auto-upload to SkyDrive is turned off?

Comment: no. its turned off .

Comment: Do you have the same problem with videos?

Comment: i didn't take any videos on that day. But i lost all the photos taken on that day. After realizing that i was deleted  some photos and took one. That photo s there but still i have '6GB' free memory also i didn't get any warning about memory

Comment: Has the phone been recently updated?

Comment: @karancan no. not recently

Comment: @Nithesh are you still facing this issue? Is it resolved? If so, would you mind posting the solution?